# Adding values into a table with a query

Tags: ms-access, vba

So all I'd like to do is add two queries into a table called `tmpGroupSearch`. I'm not sure how to do it wit out creating a record set and looping through every record and individually adding them in. I'm thinking there is a much easier way to do this I just can't find the proper structure.

Here are my queries:

```
"SELECT tblGroupHeader.GroupName" _
                           & ", tblGroupHeader.GroupNum" _
                           & ", tblAlsoKnown.AlsoKnown" _
                    & " FROM tblGroupHeader" _
                       & " LEFT JOIN tblAlsoKnown ON tblGroupHeader.GroupNum = tblAlsoKnown.GroupNum" _
                    & " WHERE tblGroupHeader.GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*'" _
                          & " OR tblGroupHeader.GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"


"Select * FROM tblActionLog WHERE AlsoKnown LIKE '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow an INSERT INTO clause with a list of values, like @Asad shows, or also a SELECT query. Do yourself a favor and always list the field names in your SQL or you are just creating time bombs for the future.

```
Dim strSelect1 As String
Dim strSelect2 As String

strSelect1 = "SELECT tblGroupHeader.GroupName" _
  & ", tblGroupHeader.GroupNum" _
  & ", tblAlsoKnown.AlsoKnown" _
  & " FROM tblGroupHeader" _
  & " LEFT JOIN tblAlsoKnown ON tblGroupHeader.GroupNum = tblAlsoKnown.GroupNum" _
  & " WHERE tblGroupHeader.GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*'" _
  & " OR tblGroupHeader.GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"

strSelect2 = "Select * FROM tblActionLog WHERE AlsoKnown LIKE '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"

Dim strInsert1 As String
Dim strInsert2 As String

strInsert1 = "INSERT INTO tmpGroupSearch (GroupName, GroupNum, AlsoKnown) " & strSelect1

'the next version is valid SQL, but *dangerous* because field names are not enumerated
strInsert2 = "INSERT INTO tmpGroupSearch " & strSelect2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two forms.

The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: Is there a way to INSERT INTO straight from a query?

Comment: Before inserting data you have to write the query.

Answer (score 1):

Test this parameter query in the Access query designer and adjust as needed so that it returns the row set you expect for the *pSearchText* parameter value you supply.

```sql
PARAMETERS pSearchText Text ( 255 );
SELECT gh.GroupName, gh.GroupNum, ak.AlsoKnown
FROM
    tblGroupHeader AS gh
    LEFT JOIN tblAlsoKnown AS ak
    ON gh.GroupNum = ak.GroupNum
WHERE
       gh.GroupName Like "'" & pSearchText & "*'"
    OR gh.GroupNum Like "'" & pSearchText & "*'"
UNION ALL
SELECT al.GroupName, al.GroupNum, al.AlsoKnown
FROM tblActionLog AS al
WHERE al.AlsoKnown Like "'" & pSearchText & "*'"
```

Once you have it returning the correct data, convert it to an `INSERT` query by changing the beginning of the statement to this ...

```sql
PARAMETERS pSearchText Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO tmpGroupSearch (GroupName, GroupNum, AlsoKnown)
SELECT gh.GroupName, gh.GroupNum, ak.AlsoKnown
... and the rest
```

Save that query as *qryGroupSearchAppend*.  Then you can execute that query from your VBA code:

```vb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryGroupSearchAppend")
qdf.Parameters("pSearchText").Value = Me.txtgroupSearch.Value
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thanks for the help hans. I wasn't able to create queries in access for this project, it had to be strictly hard coded in. So I took the easy way out and made a temp table.